# How to get the value of env file in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman, env

I have installed a rails app using the rails composer. I selected `.env` with foreman. In my `.env` file I have:

```
OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_KEY=key
```

and I am trying to get its value.

But, when I ran `ENV["OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_KEY"]` I got nil. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you restart your server after adding variable in .env file?

Comment: @Salil, yes and still no luck.

In rails console , i ran ENV["OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_KEY"] and it outpus nil

Comment: Have you restart your console?

Comment: @user2322409, yes I have. Is it because I used rails composer?

Comment: @RajShakya what do you mean you "ran"  `ENV["OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_KEY"]`?  Give us the location and code that you used to check it.

Comment: in my secrets.yml file , i have this code `omniauth_provider_key: <%= ENV["OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_KEY"] %>` but when I ran my app I got errors because the key was not found. So I tried ENV["OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_KEY"].inspect in the view but it showed me nil and again I ran it in rails console and again got nil. I am unable to get the value from .env file. @neanderslob

Comment: @RajShakya beats me man.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the dotenv gem to your gemfile:

https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv